# how to use gcloud to set disk deletion rule on an instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

As part of a startup script I use `gcloud` to create a disk from a snapshot:

`gcloud compute disks create ...`

and then attach it to the current instance

`` gcloud compute instances attach-disk `hostname` ... ``

I'd like to have this disk be deleted when the instance is deleted but I don't see the equivalent of "the "Delete Disk" Deletion rule  see in the web console when editing an instance. How can I do this with a `gcloud` command?

[image: how do delete disk rule with gcloud]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it right there in the docs: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/set-disk-auto-delete

Example:

```
gcloud compute instances set-disk-auto-delete `hostname` --disk=DISKNAME --zone=MY-ZONE
```